# Trying to read a file in chunks but can't read it in linear order?

Tags: c, parent-child, shared-memory, child-process

So I'm trying to read an input file called `f1` in chunks of 128 bytes. After reading the first 128 chars I move the pointer using sleek() to 129th char, but it still only reads the first 128 chars. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? After reading the chars, I want to store them in myBufferPointer.

This is how I create the bufferpointer in the shared memory.

```
 /* name of the shared memory buffer */
char* myBuffer = "MyBuff"; 
/* shared memory file descriptor  */
int myBufferFileDesc;
/* pointer to shared memory obect */
char *myBufferPointer;
/* create the shared memory object */

myBufferFileDesc = shm_open(myBuffer,O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666);
/* configure the size of the shared memory object */
// the size here will be buffer size * chunk size 
ftruncate(myBufferFileDesc, 3072);
/* memory map the shared memory object */
myBufferPointer = (char *)
mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myBufferFileDesc, 0);
```

The goal is to write a input file into the shared memory using read().

```
   int next_produced;
   char tempBuffer[128];
   string str;

   next_produced = read(f1, tempBuffer, 128);

   myBufferPointer += tempBuffer;

       

   printf("The conents of buffer the first time are %s\n", myBufferPointer);

 
   lseek(f1, 129, SEEK_CUR);
   read(f1, tempBuffer, 128);

   myBufferPointer += tempBuffer;



   printf("The conents of second time are %s\n", myBufferPointer);
```

Comment: You do realize that reading from the file automatically moves the read position by the exact number of characters you read, right? Because it seems that, based on our description, you believe that still need to seek past what was read. That's incorrect. Aditionally, what is the mysterious object called `myBufferPointer` all about? And what, exactly, does adding a `char` array to this mysterious object do? How is that supposed to work? If `myBufferPointer` is a `std::string`, which part of the shown code makes sure that the contents of `tempBuffer` are terminated by an explicit `\0`?

Comment: What do you find the return value from `lseek()` to be when this happens? If an error value is returned, what is the value of `errno`?

Comment: I tried putting the read() method in a for loop but kept getting the same problem. myBufferPointer is a space in the shared memory where I'm trying to read the file too. The temp buffer is just for reading the file and then adding it to the shared memory.

Comment: If this is c, why did you tag it c++

Comment: C is not C++, and neither of them are C#. They're not the same language because they all start with C, any more than a cat, a car and a caterpillar are related because they all start with *ca*. Please do not tag spam - use **only** the tags that actually apply to your question. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and misusing them is a very quick way to collect downvotes or get your post closed for being unclear.

Comment: note that on my machine that `myBufferPointer += tempBuffer;` wont even compile, I am surprised any normal c compiler accepts it

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are expecting this

```
myBufferPointer += tempBuffer;
```

to copy the read data to myBufferPointer. It will not

Since you dont show what myBufferPointer is I am going to gues that its like this

```
char buffer[1000];
char * myBufferPointer = buffer;
```

What you should do is this

```
next_produced = read(f1, myBufferPointer, 128); // read into buffer
myBufferPointer +=  next_produced;              // move pointer up by amount read

next_produced = read(f1, myBufferPointer, 128); // read into buffer
myBufferPointer +=  next_produced;              // move pointer up by amount read
```

Note that you dont need to seek if you just wan tth enext chunk

Remeber that if you want to printf this like a string you need to zero terminate it, read will not do that for you.

Comment: myBufferPointer is an object in the shared memory that I created. If I do myBufferPointer += next_produced that won't write anything into the shared memory since next_produced doesn't contain the characters from the file.

Comment: This is how I created the buffer pointer myBufferFileDesc = shm_open(myBuffer,O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666);
    
    ftruncate(myBufferFileDesc, 3072);
    
    myBufferPointer = (char *)
    mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myBufferFileDesc, 0);

Comment: @RockySingh dont post code here, edit the question,  but anyway my answer should work fine in this case

Comment: isn't nex_produced just a return value of read() which is just a number.

Comment: @RockySingh feels like you are a c#, java, javascript programmer, you are expecting that += to copy data ie  catenate strings, it doesnt. `read` returns the number of bytes read, adding that to the pointer moves the pointer up to the next free byte in the buffer, we are making `read` place each succesive read directly one after another in that buffer. Make sure it big enough though

Comment: I edit the question so you can see how I create the shared memory object

Comment: @RockySingh my answer will still work

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample that tries to do what you describe. It might help you see better, how operators and some standard calls work in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main() {
   const size_t bufferSize = 128;
   const int chunkCount = 7;

   char fileName[] = "tpm.txt";
   char tempBuffer[bufferSize + 1] = {0,};

   /* Create sample input file */
   FILE* f1 = fopen(fileName,"wb");
   if (!f1) {
      printf("Cannot open file \"%s\" for writing.\n", fileName);
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("* Writing %d chunks of %lld bytes to \"%s\".\n\n",chunkCount,bufferSize,fileName);

   for (int i=1;i<= chunkCount;i++) {
      memset(tempBuffer, '0'+i, bufferSize );
      fwrite(tempBuffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, f1);
   }
   fclose(f1);

   /* Read back input file */
   f1 = fopen(fileName, "rb");
   if (!f1) {
      printf("Cannot open file \"%s\" for reading.\n", fileName);
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("* Reading %lld byte chunks from \"%s\".\n\n", bufferSize, fileName);

   size_t next_produced=1;
   memset(tempBuffer, '0', bufferSize);
   tempBuffer[bufferSize] = 0;

   for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
      next_produced = fread(tempBuffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, f1);
      
      if ( 0 >= next_produced )
         break;

      printf("The contents of buffer are:\n%s\n", tempBuffer);
   }
}
```